# Use '+' as a route separator

Tags: symfony, routes

In the first versions of Sf2 (first Beta's), there was an option, to declare your route separators, like

```
options: { segment_separators: ['/'] }
```

But now, it is out of use, and i'm searching the way, to make pretty routes, like:

```
category:
pattern: /category+{cat}+page{page}
defaults: { _controller: MyPrettyBundle:Category:index }
```

And now i get this error:

No route found for "GET /category firstcategory page1"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException

As you can see, '+' is just cutted out of required route.

Any ideas how can i overcome this nasty error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fix issues with url decoding](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3780)!

Answer (score 0):

For URL encoding the `+` character is used to encode spaces. The URL is decoded before it's parsed, so to use actual `+` characters in the URL you would have to encode them as `%2B`:

```
/category%2Bfirstcategory%2Bpage1
```

That's not pretty, so using `+` as separator is not a good idea.